# dnn uxguide not helpful

Tags: html, dotnetnuke

The DNN uxguide

http://uxguide.dotnetnuke.com/

purports to provide patterns that would be useful in writing DNN modules, but many of them do not work correctly.

Take the Simple Form Demo - if I use the Markup provided, including

```
<dnn:Label runat="server" ControlName="NameTextBox" ResourceKey="Name" />
```

in a control, I get this error:

Unknown server tag 'dnn:Label'.

If I pick up the HTML generated by the uxguide site and drop it into a DNN HTML module, then the elements end up all over the place.

It's hard to understand what use these examples are when they do not function correctly when added to a vanilla DNN installation. I am trying to replace Bootstrap CSS - which of course works perfectly.

Any idea of how to use these uxguide elements?

Ta
JC

Answer (score 0):

DNN hero Sebastian explains:

The UX Guide was created for DNN 6 and UX has been overhauled in DNN 7 and 8 - unfortunately without providing a similar guide. You should have a look at the latest module development templates - either MVC or SPA, which are now methods of choice. Another starting point might be the modules from DNN 8 contest (see the Community section of this site).